# In Memory Image to Zipfile

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I wrote this code :

```
with Image.open(objective.picture.read()) as image:
    image_file = BytesIO()
    exifdata = image.info['exif']
    image.save(image_file, 'JPEG', quality=50, exif=exifdata)
    zf.writestr(zipped_filename, image_file)
```

Which is supposed to open the image stored in my model (this is in a Django application). I want to reduce the quality of the image file before adding it to the zipfile (zf). So I decided to work with BytesIO to prevent writing useless file on the disk. Though I'm getting an error here. It says :
 `embedded NUL character`
Could someone help me out with this ? I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Where does that error occur? Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: Also, not sure you need the `BytesIO` object here... `image` objects have a `.tobytes()` method anyway...

Comment: I don't get it. How am I supposed to modify the image without creating a new one ? It all happens when I execute the save function, though I don't really know how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you specifically need to [pass in a bytestring to `writestr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr). That means you should either do what Jon suggested or you should use `image_file.read()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was kind of dumb. objective.picture.read() returns a byte string (really long byte string...) so I shouldn't have used `Image` but `ImageFile.Parser()` and feed that byte string to the parser so it can return an Image that I can work with. Here is the code :

```
from PIL import ImageFile
from io import BytesIO

p = ImageFile.Parser()
p.feed(objective.picture.read())
image = p.close()
image_file = BytesIO()
exifdata = image.info['exif']
image.save(image_file, 'JPEG', quality=50, exif=exifdata)
# Here zf is a zipfile writer
zf.writestr(zipped_filename, image_file.getvalue())
```

The `close()` actually returns the image parsed from the bytestring.
Here is the doc : [The ImageFile Documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFile.html)

Comment: If you just click the link, there is a full example with imports and stuff. Though you're right, I'm adding those right now.